# Lua - math.random () isn't working

Tags: random, lua, lua-table

In the beginning of my program I initialise the random number generator with:

```
math.randomseed (os.time ())
math.random (); math.random (); math.random ()
```

In another function, I want to call math.random when the variable `pc` has a value of nil:

```
function playervspc2 ()
    if pc == nil then
        pc = math.random (1, 7)
    end
end
```

This does give a random number, but repeats this number when `playervspc2` is called again during runtime:

```
while win == 0 do
    playervspc1 ()
    windetect (playername)
    if win == 1 then
        break
    end
    playervspc2 ()
    windetect ("The PC")
end
```

When math.random is called without the condition that `pc == nil`, it gives perfectly random numbers. I have checked that `pc` is really nil just before the the `if pc == nil` statement starts.

Comment: You said you checked `pc` is really `nil`, but the it's not in the code you show. Provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that second call to your function doesn't do anything, as `pc` (which is probably global value, is not `nil` anymore, instead it has a value which was randomly generated first time, thus the condition `if pc == nil` is false and nothing happens. Change it to

```
function playervspc2 ()
  pc = math.random(1,7)
end
```

And it will provide you with random pc every time you call it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by using `pc`. Here is my answer based on what I understood:

It looks like `pc` is local variable and has not been defined before it is used.

Try defining `pc` from the calling module, assign `pc` an initial value then pass that to the called module.